# How to pass a variable to setInterval?

Tags: jquery, ajax, setinterval

I need to update the time in my `setInterval`. The value is returned by the function that `setInterval` is executing.

`read_log();` returns an integer.

```
var loop = setInterval(function(){count = read_log();}, count);
```

This returns that `count` is undefiend. So I need to get the count and pass it to `setInterval`

Comment: Of course it does. `count` is not set when `setInterval` is executed. It is set AFTER `setInterval` is executed. Does `read_log()` pass a different value everytime?

Comment: You don't need to pass `count` as an argument. The second argument to `setInterval` is the repetition period in milliseconds.

Comment: @Barmar I know but I need it to be a variable, not a constant. And this variable needs to be set by the `read_log()` function.

Comment: Why are you using the same variable for the repeat interval as you use for the return value from `read_log()`?

Comment: What you're doing makes no sense. You need to set the repetition interval before it calls `read_log()`.

Comment: @putvande yes, `read_log()` does pass a different value everytime.

Comment: @Barmar I know, that is why I am asking for help. I need to pass a value to `setInterval` everytime `read_log()` is executed. And this value is returned by `read_log()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to change the repetition interval after each call to `read_log()`, you can't use `setInterval()` -- that uses a constent repetition. You need to use `setTimeout`, so you can change the period each time:

```
function call_read_log() {
    var count = read_log();
    setTimeout(call_read_log, count);
}
call_read_log();
```

Comment: Great! This is what I was looking for. I also had to change my `read_log` function so it can return the `count` Here is a good tutorial on how to make a proper `$.ajax` call http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call